# Laravel Validation based on the value of nested array

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have read a couple of Stack overflow questions about nested array but I want something a step further. Lets say something like the code below:

I have a validator snippet where the request takes an array.  Based on what I understood, on `xxx.*.yyy`, it will find all array of `xxx` with `yyy` as key and validate them . However, what if I want to validate the `image_id` and `image_path` based on the value of `type`?

Note: type, title, image_id and image_path are all on the same level.

The array that I want to validate is like this:

```
[contents] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [type] => not_image
                [title] => title
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [type] => image
                [image_id] => 13
                [image_path] => some_image_string
            )
        )
    )
```

while my validator is this:

```
$v = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'contents.*.type' => ['string', 'required', Rule::in(['image', 'not_image']),],
    'contents.*.image_id' => ['required', 'integer'],
    'contents.*.image_path' => ['required', 'string', 'min:2', 'max:500'],
]);
```

Only validated image_id and image_page if type is image where image_id and image_path would only be validated if type is validated. I know that the code is missing that one ingredient to do what I want. If you have other ideas on how to do this, that would also be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your last code is not valid, you are saying `type => string, required, rule::in, image_id => [rules]`, that is not valid, that post you are following is just badly indented...

There is a specific section in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#conditionally-adding-rules) that talks and shows about this...

The rule you have to use is `exclude_if`, the documentation states:

> You may occasionally wish to not validate a given field if another field has a given value. You may accomplish this using the `exclude_if` validation rule. In this example, the `appointment_date` and `doctor_name` fields will not be validated if the `has_appointment` field has a value of `false`

And the example they give is:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
 
$validator = Validator::make($data, [
    'has_appointment' => 'required|boolean',
    'appointment_date' => 'exclude_if:has_appointment,false|required|date',
    'doctor_name' => 'exclude_if:has_appointment,false|required|string',
]);
```

As you can see, if the `has_appointment` is `false` (`exclude_if:has_appointment,false`), then `appointment_date` and `doctor_name` will not be validated.

In your case, it should be like:

```php
Validator::make(
    $request->all(),
    [
        'contents.*.type' => ['string', 'required', Rule::in(['image', 'not_image'])],
        'contents.*.image_id' => ['exclude_unless:contents.*.type,image', 'required', 'integer'],
        'contents.*.image_path' => ['exclude_unless:contents.*.type,image', 'required', 'string', 'min:2', 'max:500'],
        'contents.*.title' => ['exclude_unless:contents.*.type,not_image', 'required', 'string'],
    ]
);
```

What that validator is going to do is:

- Only when `contents.*.type = image`, then `image_id`, and `image_path` are going to be validated
- Only when `contents.*.type = non_image`, then `title` is going to be validated

See that I have used the opposite of `exclude_if`, that is `exclude_unless`. So we are saying `exclude_unless:contents.*.type,image` => If `contents.*.type` IS `image`, then use whatever rules I have after this, else completely ignore this field.

---

You can write it using `exclude_if` and it would be like this:

```php
Validator::make(
    $request->all(),
    [
        'contents.*.type' => ['string', 'required', Rule::in(['image', 'not_image'])],
        'contents.*.image_id' => ['exclude_if:contents.*.type,non_image', 'required', 'integer'],
        'contents.*.image_path' => ['exclude_if:contents.*.type,non_image', 'required', 'string', 'min:2', 'max:500'],
        'contents.*.title' => ['exclude_if:contents.*.type,image', 'required', 'string'],
    ]
);
```

The difference (appart from `exclude_if` instead of `exclude_unless`) is that now you are ONLY excluding if `image` or `non_image`, but using `exclude_unless` is saying: Only validate if `image` (or `non_image`), so if you have 3 types instead of 2 (`image` and `non_image`), `exclude_if` will not work, because you can't specify more than 1 value.

---

Another quick tip is: just use `$request->validate()` instead of `Validator::make`:

```php
$request->validate([
    'contents.*.type' => ['string', 'required', Rule::in(['image', 'not_image'])],
    'contents.*.image_id' => ['exclude_unless:contents.*.type,image', 'required', 'integer'],
    'contents.*.image_path' => ['exclude_unless:contents.*.type,image', 'required', 'string', 'min:2', 'max:500'],
    'contents.*.title' => ['exclude_unless:contents.*.type,not_image', 'required', 'string'],
]);
```

Comment: Wow. thank you for giving me insights. Will try to implement this as soon as I can. Will let you know. Thank you again. As per you comment the code is not properly indented, thank you for correcting me.

Comment: I read it as adding the image id and path inside the type.

Comment: deleted that snippet.

Comment: This is great. yeah it works. I can also do an AND condition on this. I think we can do an OR on the exclude but I dont need it for now.